# user login using session not working

Tags: asp.net, sql

i need to retrive some data from table registration of database to show.aspx page after login. when i register a new user after registration and  redirect it to the profile.aspx page then it works fine(showing all required data). but if i do logout and again do login to the same user then the page show.aspx show nothing

I am using this code for user login:

```
Protected Sub btnLogin_Click1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim admin As String = "Admin"
    Dim objcmd As New SqlCommand(("select * from Login where UserName='" + txtUserName1.Text & "' And Password='") + txtPassword1.Text & "'", con)
    Dim objReader As SqlDataReader

    con.Open()
    objReader = objcmd.ExecuteReader()
    If objReader.HasRows Then
        While objReader.Read()
            If [String].Compare(objReader("UserType").ToString(), admin) = 0 Then
                Session("UserName_Admin") = txtUserName.Text.ToString().Trim()
                Session("UserName") = txtUserName.Text.ToString().Trim()
                Response.Redirect("adminview.aspx")
            Else
                Session("UserName") = txtUserName.Text.ToString().Trim()
                Response.Redirect("show.aspx")
            End If
        End While
    Else
        lblLoginMessage.Text = "Login failed. Please try again"
    End If
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

code in the show.aspx page

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    If Session("UserName") Is Nothing Then

        Response.Redirect("registration.aspx")

    End If

    binddata()

End Sub
Sub binddata()

    Dim mycommand As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM registration where UserName = @UserName", con)
    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Session("UserName").ToString())
    con.Open()
    ProfileData.DataSource = mycommand.ExecuteReader
    ProfileData.DataBind()
    con.Close()
End Sub
Protected Sub LinkButton1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Response.Redirect("upimg.aspx")
End Sub
```

i am using a datalist to retrieve data from database in show.aspx page. 
is there anything i need to change in web.config file . a help will be appreciated

Comment: I would *seriously* recommend changing your first section of code where you are concatenating the username and password into a string. This is a clear SQL injection attack target. Use parametrised queries instead as you have lower down the the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your logout code clearing the session values?

I think you would be far better off using the ASP.net Membership and Roles to handle this functionality because it will be much more secure and flexible.

[Check out here an article explaining how to get setup here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/24/ASP.NET-2.0-Membership_2C00_-Roles_2C00_-Forms-Authentication_2C00_-and-Security-Resources-.aspx)

Comment: Session.RemoveAll()
        Response.Redirect("registration.aspx")   for the logout code

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with @John Mc, using the Membership provider would be a much better idea.

As to clearing out session info, you should use:

```
Session.Clear()
Session.Abandon()
```